# htmlunit execute page javascript

Tags: javascript, html, htmlunit

I am trying get the content of a web page after the execution of the javascript code in the page. Let's suppose for example that I have the following page :

```
<html>
<body>
  test:
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = "Hello World!";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want to extract is the page after the execution of the javascript, so the rendered html :

```
<html>
<body>
  test:
  <div id="inner">Hello World</div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible in htmlUnit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTMLUnit executing form with javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242365/htmlunit-executing-form-with-javascript-code) or [HTMLUnit doesn't wait for Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555178/htmlunit-doesnt-wait-for-javascript/5723773#5723773)

Comment: Well, this is not a duplicate. I wait only for the page to load. The script is executed when the page is loaded. Does it have the same ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what issue you are having with that code but it works perfectly for me.

I created a file with that content and the result I got from fetching the content of the page was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>

  test:

    <div id="inner">
      Hello World!
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = "Hello World!";

//]]>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is all the code you need:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("the_url");
System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

You might also find this question useful:

- [JavaScript not being properly executed in HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646612/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly. `htmlUnit` does support execution of JavaScript code.. Check out [this tutorial](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/javascript-howto.html) it might help you get started.

Also if you're doing application testing in a professional enviroment, especially if it's on a larger scale, then I would like to advice you to use something a bit more advanced than `htmlUnit`, for example [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29).