# How can I type something into a Javascript page using Java?

Tags: java, javascript, html

I apologize if this question is somewhere else already, but I didn't know what to search for to find it.

The goal of what I want to accomplish is that I want to interact with JavaScript components that are on a URL page dusing Java. For example, if I have the text field:

```
<input type="text" class = "input_text" name = "notes" maxlength="100"
       style="width:100px" placeholder = "Extra Notes" />
```

how can I have Java type something into the text field?

To be more specific, there are a couple of text fields and then 2 drop down menus that need to have data input to them. Then I need to press a button, which sends the information to the server.

The other option, if this isn't possible, would be to send the information directly to their server. That would actually be the ideal way to do it, but how could I find exactly what is being sent to the server by pressing F12?

Thank you, and I hope that made sense. If not, please tell me what I need to clarify and I will do my best to explain.

EDIT: I never understand why I get negative reviews when I post something I don't know a lot about. There will be other people with this same question, who don't know a lot about the Chrome developing tools (which is what I think F12 opens), and will find this question useful. The reason why I couldn't find an answer to my question is just that: People people who know a lot about the topic, and see a question like this downvote it because it doesn't sound proper.

So let's not downvote, and instead explain what is wrong with the question so I can start looking in the right direction, and others can learn as well.

EDIT 2: After exploring everything for a while, and learning a bit of JavaScript, it appears that the "Post" button submits the entire form. On submit, it checks to make sure that certain fields in the form aren't blank.

The form starts with `<form action = "http://example/index.php?.......section=action&amp;do=example-here"...... />`. Exactly what is that URL? (Obviously "Example" being replaced with the actual website name). When I link to it, it says invalid request. I can't find "example-here" (the actual text) anywhere else anywhere. I would think that URL is the key to posting what I need to post, but I just can't figure out how to use it. Is that URL what I need?

Comment: Once I get this sorted out, I will do my best to re-write the question to be easier to understand for future viewers. I suppose it came out as confused text because it came out of a very confused brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interact with a dynamic web page you would need to use frameworks like [`HtmlUnit`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) that have support for javascript.

> HtmlUnit is a "GUI-Less browser for Java programs". It models HTML
>   documents and provides an API that allows you to invoke pages, fill
>   out forms, click links, etc... just like you do in your "normal"
>   browser.

You requirement to fill `HTML` forms is well understood by such apis and can dynamically invoke the js/ajax components to interact with your server side too.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll look into that. I'm about to add a bit more to my question, if you could take a look at that and see if this still applies, that would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3144349 your edit isn't absolutely clear to me, however you don't want to hit the url directly with htmlunit. You fill in the form as a step by step process and invoke submit (or a js or an Ajax call) and that's it. You can refer to its documentation as it aligns to your requirement

Comment: Ah, okay, I think understand now. You create the form with htmlunit, and then submit it to the url to be processed?

Comment: @user3144349 well, yes and no. You don't "create" a form with HtmlUnit, you just create an object of what your framework defines as a handle to your html form - check a few examples out, to start with, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242365/htmlunit-executing-form-with-javascript-code)

Comment: @user3144349 also, you might want to accept the answer for closure

Answer (score 0):

There is no JavaScript here. The stuff you've posted that you're calling JavaScript is HTML.

An HTML form submitted over HTTP has a pretty standard form. Look at the `<form>` tag's `action` attribute to find out the URL to submit to, and its `<input>` tags to find out the params to submit with it.

Here's a working example which posts a form then dumps the result page to System.out:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.* ;
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://example/index.php?.......section=action&do=example-here");
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("notes", "some silly text here");
        params.put("other params that are in your form", "blah");

        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));
    }
}
```

This example uses the fake URL from your question, which should be changed to the real URL of course. Note that `&amp;` is not part of the URL; it's simply the HTML encoding of the `&` character.

If the real form requires being logged in, or has any `<input>` element which changes with each request of the form page, you'll need to do more work to mimic the real form though, in which case @PopoFibo's answer is probably the simplest way to do it.