# HTMLUnit doesn't wait for Javascript 2

Tags: java, ajax, htmlunit

I have the same problem as posted in this topic:
[HTMLUnit doesn't wait for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555178/htmlunit-doesnt-wait-for-javascript/5728109#5728109)
The solution partly helped (using BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24), as previously page wasn't even displayed properly, at least now is, however I'm stuck on ...Loading... message, which i checked in browser and it takes up to 10 seconds to show results.
Then I tried to use other code posted there, so my looks pretty much like this:

```
HtmlPage htmlPage = null;
try {
  htmlPage = submit.click();
  int i = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
  while (i > 0)
  {
    i = webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    System.out.println(i);

    if (i == 0)
    {
      break;
    }
    synchronized (htmlPage)
    {
      System.out.println("wait");
      try {
        htmlPage.wait(500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By clicking, I'm submitting the form. Any ideas? Im new in HtmlUnit, so please be lenient.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this. Additionally, I wouldn't recommend using the `waitForBackgroundJavaScript` method either. Furthermore, the HTMLUnit API itself doesn't recommend it.

I've explained in this question a better and simpler way to work with AJAX:

[Get the changed HTML content after it's updated by Javascript? (htmlunit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843521/get-the-changed-html-content-after-its-updated-by-javascript-htmlunit)