# WebClient(htmlunit) doesn't see some elements

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to parse the webpage for the steam marketplace using "page.asText()", but this does not work. This might happen because items aren't being loaded after the html is loaded in 1 second.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
            String link="http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=730#p6_price_asc";
            HtmlPage page;
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(link);
            System.out.println(page.asText());
            }
```

In the console I see:

```
Show advanced options...






 < 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 939 >
 Showing 1-10 of 9389 results
```

It needs to be:

```
Show advanced options...
PRICE
QUANTITY
NAME
31,218
 Starting at:
 $0.35 USD
Operation Hydra Case 
 Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
 276,582
 Starting at:
 $0.23 USD
.
.
.

M4A1-S | Decimator (Field-Tested) 
 Counter-Strike: Global Offensive


 232
 Starting at:
 $27.06 USD

AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred) 
 Counter-Strike: Global Offensive


 28,068
 Starting at:
 $0.75 USD

Krakow 2017 Legends Autograph Capsule 
 Counter-Strike: Global Offensive


 < 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 940 >
 Showing 1-10 of 9392 results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure javascript is enabled.

```
webClient.getOptions.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

What I typically do in order to wait for more elements to load is:

```
thread.sleep(3000);
```

This gives the page 3 seconds to load all additional content.

You can also try any of the other methods listed by other users here:

[HTMLUnit doesn't wait for Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555178/htmlunit-doesnt-wait-for-javascript)

Comment: when need to use "thread.sleep(3000);"? WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    
    page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(link);
    System.out.println(page.asText());

Comment: You will need to use thread.sleep() after webClient.getPage(link).

Comment: WOW."getPage(link)" always reload? i think getPage one time and all. Thank u. so much)

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful to you, please consider up voting my answer and accepting it. Thanks.